# how to display mysql data with group by once every type in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result set like this :

```
Platform   Set   Total
WinY1-23   OT    12
WinY1-23   TT    22
WinY1-23   OR    13
WinY1-23   OY    142
Total_WS   OT    12
Total_WS   TT    12
Total_WS   OR    13
```

Basically this is a query with group by `Platform`, `Set`. I want to be able to display each Set and its total within each Platform. Hope this makes sense. 
Is there any way to display just once the `Platform` and the Sets under it?
In SSRS we can show something similar , as the report displays `+` sign for each of this Platform type. Can we do this in PHP? or by any other means?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "display" - the rendering of the HTML markup?

Comment: Maybe so it's easier for us to understand, you could show us the result you wanna have,  and the actual query.

Comment: @KM its interesting to know that there is such an algorithm. This is what I want, but not sure how to implement it in PHP. Thansk @Pekka, @Daan for trying to help. The results that I want is given by @Sinan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asssuming what you want is something like this:

```
$platform = '';
foreach($resultSetArray as $row){
  // if platform is different from previous one
  // display platform
  if($row['platform'] != $platform){
    echo $row['platform'];
    $platform = $row['platform'];
  }

  echo $row['otherStuff'];
}


WinY1-23   
OT    12
TT    22
OR    13
OY    142
Total_WS
OT    12
TT    12
OR    13
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming what you want is something like that and if you have some other data which is not in any group that will be show with title other or something you like.

```
     $i=1
     foreach($result as $row){
            $platform;

            if ($row['platform'] != $platform && !empty($row['platform'])) {
                ?>
                <div>
                    <h1> <?php echo $row['platform']; ?></h1>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php

            if ( empty($row['platform']) && $i==1 ) {

                ?>
                <div>
                    <h1> <?php  "Other"; ?> </h1>
                </div>
    <?php $i=2; } ?>
    <?php
    $platform = $row['platform'];
     }
```